# UML - Representing third party libraries in class diagram

Tags: uml, visio, class-diagram, rational-rose

Could somebody guide me on representing third party libraries in a class diagram.

For instance I am trying to draw a class diagram for my logging functionality. Which internally uses 'log4net' for logging. And I want to represent 'log4net' in my class diagram as a third party library(may be another assembly).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put 'log4net' classes in separate package. Use dependency as the relationship between them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pawel, you have to put the 'log4net' class outside your modelling. According to the tool you use, ouside your model could be in another package, another model, another component.